# How to use SQL Server to get data of appointed time?

Tags: sql-server

I use this sql to get data 16 months ago. I've written too much. I don't think it's a good way to do it.

ModifyDate is of `datetime` datatype.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable_1
WHERE 
    LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ModifyDate, 112), 6) = 
        CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -16, GETDATE())) AS varchar(4)) + 
            CASE WHEN CAST(MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -16, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(2)) < 10 
                    THEN '0' + CAST(MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -16, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(1))
                    ELSE CAST(MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -16, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(2))
            END
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting date to varchar doesn't look good idea. You can use `datetime` type and standard functions.

```
declare @dateminus16 datetime = DATEADD(month,-16,getdate())
select * from MyTable_1
where year(ModifyDate) = year(@dateminus16)
and month(ModifyDate) = month(@dateminus16)
```

Comment: This is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `ModifyDate`  is a `DateTime` data type and is in UTC time, then this should get you the records that have been modified 16 months ago or earlier

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable_1 where ModifyDate <= dateadd(month, -16, getutcdate());
```

Comment: This will not work @Leo, you need to code `ModifyDate` like this : `month(ModifyDate)` for it to work. Just a heads up. :-)

Comment: Either way, you answer is the simplest and straight to the point. Exactly the answer I would like to see...